# Python: Skip an Iteration in a For Loop if a condition is true

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, if-statement, continue

I have written a Python script that reads in values from an Excel worksheet and iterates through the rows.

However, I would like the program to skip a row if a certain condition is met.

I have an xml file that has a value that determines the run type. In the python code, I have written an If / Else block to convert the value to a number (see below)

```
# If / Else to convert test_run_type text to a value
if test_run_type == "Regression":
    test_run_type_value = '1'
elif test_run_type == "Smoke":
    test_run_type_value = '2'
elif test_run_type == "Sanity":
    test_run_type_value = '3'
```

Next, I have the for loop which iterates through the rows (see code below)

```
# Open Test Scenario Workbook; Instantiate worksheet object
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(test_case_directory, Product + '.xlsx'))
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

## Begin For Loop to iterate through Test Scenarios
        i = 1
        rows = sh.nrows
        empty_cell = False
        for x in range(1, sh.nrows):

            cell_val = sh.cell(i, 0).value
            if cell_val == '':
                # If Cell Value is empty, set empty_cell to True
                empty_cell = True
            else:
                # If Cell Value is NOT empty, set empty_cell to False
                empty_cell = False


            regression_check = sh.cell_value(i, 3)
            smoke_check = sh.cell_value(i, 4)
            sanity_check = sh.cell_value(i, 5)

            # If / Else Section to check if a test needs to be run
            #### Program is running ALL rows & NOT skipping rows

            if test_run_type_value == 3 and sanity_check == "False":
                    continue
            else:
                pass

            if test_run_type_value == 2 and smoke_check == "False":
                    continue
            else:
                pass

            if test_run_type_value == 1 and regression_check == "False":
                    continue
            else:
                pass
```

The Problem: My expectation is that the program will skip a row if one of the following scenarios occur in a row.

- test_run_type_value is "3" and sanity_check equals False
- test_run_type_value is "2" and smoke_check equals False
- test_run_type_value is "1" and regression_check equals False

However, the program is NOT skipping any of the rows.

I took a screenshot of the Excel sheet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxHqN.png)

Based on the worksheet (see attached image), the program should skip the first row when the test_run_type_value is "3" but it is not. The program iterates through all the rows (even when the test_run_type_value is 1, 2 or 3)

Thanks in Advance

Ken

Comment: `else: pass` is completely pointless, you should leave it out.

Comment: `test_run_type_value = '3'`  against `test_run_type_value == 3`

Answer (score 0):

```
test_run_type_value = '1'
```

This sets `test_run_type_value` to the **string** value `'1'`.

```
if test_run_type_value == 1 …
```

This compares `test_run_type_value` to the **integer** value `1`.

So you are basically comparing strings and integers here, and those are never equal:

```
>>> '1' == 1
False
```

So decide on whether you want to use a string, or an integer. E.g. if you assign `1`, it should work fine:

```
test_run_type_value = 1 # no quotes => int!
```

Btw. you do not need to do this:

```
else:
    pass
```

Simply don’t include an else, and nothing will be done if the condition is not true:

```
if test_run_type_value == 3 and sanity_check == "False":
    continue
if test_run_type_value == 2 and smoke_check == "False":
    continue
if test_run_type_value == 1 and regression_check == "False":
    continue
```